# Dynamics CRM 2011 Set Quotes Revision Number

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am tasked with importing data from a CRM 3.0 instance into a CRM 2011 instance via the service layer.  I've completed most of the entities but I hit a snag with Quotes.  Revising a Quote creates a copy of the Quote and then increment its Revision Number.  Revision Number is a read only field in the 2011 Service Layer.  This creates a serious problem as you can imagine.  Is there some other way to set this?

*Update*
There is a ReviseQuoteRequest that will allow you to create a new revision of the Quote.  The only problem with this is that I am trying to keep the same Guids when importing Entities.  You can set the Guid to assign when you create a new Quote, but I don't see a way to tell the ReviseQuoteRequest what Guid to use when creating the Quote Revision and I don't believe the API allows you to Update this ID once its set.  Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Revised Quotes are not handled this way and so the Revision Number cannot be directly set.

In order to Revise a Quote you need to use the ReviseQuoteRequest which effectively closes the original quote and creates a new Quote, copying the values from the original and incrementing the Revision Number behind the scenes.

Comment: To elaborate on this further, you can't bring over just a certain revision of a quote AND have it keep the revision number.  The only way to do this is to import each revision in order using the ReviseQuoteRequest which will automatically increment the revision number for you.